# Getting 404 on a routed page with Vite and React Router v6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, vite

I am having a little issue with routing, my routing is working as intended however there is a slight quirk I can't figure out.

I have two routes:

- `domain.com`
- `domain.com/logs`

On `domain.com` I have the following header.

```js
<nav className="space-x-4">
          <Link to="/">
            <LinkButton btnText="Home" />
          </Link>
          <Link to="/logs">
            <LinkButton btnText="Logs" />
          </Link>
</nav>
```

Clicking through on these links works fine as expected. However when I am on `domain.com/logs` and refresh the page i get a 404. Below is how I have set up my routing.

```js
import Logs from './routes/Logs'

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'))
root.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<App />} />
      <Route path="/logs" element={<Logs />} />
    </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>
)
```

I have come across this link: https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/edge-network/frequently-asked-questions#why-do-i-see-a-404-error-when-accessing-my-deployment

I am building from the whole dir so should include the `routes` folder.

Now I am not sure if this is something to do with Vercel or Vite. Any suggestions would be great. Also to note this...works perfectly locally so must be a build thing.

Answer (score 1):

The index.html that serves up your website when you visit `domain.com` also needs to be served up when you visit `domain.com/logs` your client side routing will then work.

The react-router will then show your app in its correct state.

More info can be found here describing deployments with client side routing
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#serving-apps-with-client-side-routing

im not familiar with vercel but they will probably have a wildcard option to serve the index document up for any unresolved routes.

Comment: Is there a way to fix this issue in Vite?

Comment: Same question as above. There's nothing out there to tell you how to fix it for .net core/vite/react with or without docker - I don't want to have to add nginx just to solve one silly redirect problem!

Answer (score 1):

user3928944 is exactly right. You need to serve your index page when you visit `domain.com/logs`.

On vercel, you can do this by creating a [redirect rule](https://vercel.com/docs/projects/project-configuration#redirects).

Create a file named `vercel.json` in your project root and add the following to it:

```
{
  "routes": [{ "src": "/[^.]+", "dest": "/", "status": 200 }]
}
```